# Multiple rows to one unique comma-separated value

Tags: mysql

I want to return data in **unique action_id (comma separated values)** from a table using singme SQL query

For example table: tbl_action

```
action_id
----------
101
102
103     
104
102
105

Output that I want is: 101,102,103,104,105
```

Comment: Marked duplicate because the OP showed no effort at a query, or any research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with `Distinct`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT action_id) FROM tbl_action;
```

If you want the `action_id` values to be in ascending order in the comma separated string, you can do the following:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT action_id ORDER BY action_id) 
FROM tbl_action;
```

Comment: Thanks it working now...